# Are Heroku Postgres databases unavailable during maintenance windows?

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm confused by this:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-maintenance

When a maintenance window is occurring, does that mean the database will be unavailable and give errors if your app tries to read/write to it? Is this the same for all plans?

Comment: answer is in the first paragraph... Offline means unavailable...
"From time to time, Heroku must take your database OFFLINE to perform maintenance tasks."

Comment: @AnyMoose And this is the same for all plans? How is this not a big issue for a highly available app? Don't they do follower/changeover updates for you to avoid downtime?

Comment: it appears all plans will have maintenance performed. with the higher cost plans you can schedule the maintenance, but it will still happen.
if you need high availability, you will need a cluster of databases with each node scheduled for a different maintenance window.

Comment: @AnyMoose OK, thanks. I thought Heroku would have some option to avoid downtime like this hence the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

As the document says, we have not been facing connection error for our app to run for about 2 years with a HA plan.

> For example, for HA plans (premium, private, and shield), we try to
>   use failover whenever we can, unless it’s a follower of another
>   database already. For non-HA plans (standard) and followers regardless
>   of plan, we mainly use changeover.

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-maintenance